# Styling bootstrap buttons in mvc is killing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using VS and mvc. I have a Html.BeginForm which takes a randomKey as a string in the input box. There is a retrieve button that currently abuts the input box and I just want to add a margin to the button. In the site.css there is a .retrieveButton class but it doesn't seem to override the bootstrap css. Help please!

```
  <div>
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RandomKey...placeholder = "Enter your 8 digit key" } })
 <div class="form-group">
       <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Retrieve" class="btn btn-default retrieveButton"/>
       </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of duplicate class names, the last CSS file wins (it augments or redefines what came before it).

So make sure that your CSS files are added to the page in the correct order. Probably your personal CSS should come *after* Bootstrap CSS. To do this for MVC 4+, see file **App_Start -> BundleConfig.cs**.

For more in-depth info about bundling in MVC see e.g. this: http://timgthomas.com/2012/09/a-quick-start-of-asp-net-mvc-4s-bundling/

Answer (score 1):

You can try using !important in the CSS or you can try using a more direct selector.

When you have multiple statements that try to apply the same property to the same element then the statement with the more precise selector will be used.

try:

```
.form-group > .btn.btn-default.retrieveButton {
}
```

You can read more about this here:

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/